# Intl.DateTimeFormat() - return weekday as number?

Tags: javascript, datetime

It appears Intl.DateTimeFormat() only accepts `"narrow", "short", "long"` as the `weekday` option. I would like it to return as a `number`. i.e. Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 and so on. If I'm correct in reading "numerical" is not an option, what would be an easy way to return the value weekday as a number?

```
const day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    timeZone: America/New_York,
    weekday: 'long',
});

const weekdayNumber = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
const dayNumber = weekdayNumber[day.format(now)];
console.log('Weekday: ' + dayNumber); // returns error
```

Comment: If a certain locale uses numeric weekdays in any of their short/narrow/whatever forms (e.g. Chinese I believe?), then that’s what will be used. If no locale does so by default, then this is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way would be [`Date.prototype.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

```js
const dayNumber = new Date().getDay();

console.log(dayNumber);
```

If by all means you want to use something to "look it up", this would be one approach to get the weekday as a number:

```js
const day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'America/New_York',
    weekday: 'long',
});

const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const dayNumber = weekdays.indexOf(day.format(Date.now()));

console.log(dayNumber);
```

Comment: The second example was perfect for my needs. Thank you!!